# "Hey you! Yes you!" or "Hey you! Yes, you!"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I am getting married and we are having save the dates made with the wording - hey you, yes you! Our mom and dad are getting married, so save that date!

> Hey you! Yes you!

or

> Hey you! Yes, you!

Comment: I'd use two commas: _Hey, you! Yes, you!_ But if you want your question taken seriously on a site designed for linguists and serious etymologists, you'd be better off changing your title. For one, try spelling "english" with an upper-case E; for another, this is more of a punctuation question than a grammatical one.

Comment: Congratulations!  Use two commas as J.R. suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you want the words to be read?  I understand your words as -

*Hey you* - calling out.

*Yes you* - making clear who you are addressing.

I suppose your aim is to be attention grabbing and fun, so you could write -

***Hey!***

***You!***

***Yes... YOU!!***

Or even,

***Ye-es... YOU!!***

Comment: What the h---!  +1